# display centered equations from code cells

Tags: jupyter-notebook

I have generated some LaTeX in a Jupyter notebook cell

```
env = (r'\begin{align}' +
       r'\\'.join('a_{%d} &= %d'%(i, i) for i in range(9,11)) +
       r'\end{align}')
```

that I can print, `print(env)`, and copy & paste in a markdown cell to have
a nice displayed equation, that is a *centered* equation.

On the other hand, if I use IPython's facilites to directly display the LaTeX
snippet

```
from IPython.display import display, Latex
display(Latex(env))
```

the equation is displayed left aligned, with no margin at all.

Is it possible to convince the `display` machinery to (maybe optionally) display equations where we are used to see them?

---

*Addendum*
<sup>(2019-05-13)</sup>

---

I'm happy to report that passing `env` into a call to `IPython.display.HTML` renders the LaTeX code using MathJax, but, alas, the Jupyter notebook insists in aligning the math block to the left...

[image]